# How to access external json file objects in vue.js app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How to access *JSON* objects in the **vue.js** app I am new in this

```
import json from './json/data.json'
```

the JSON file is loaded and now I have to access the objects within it

Comment: Do you want to display the data from JSON  to HTML template

Comment: yes i want to display in html format

Comment: are you using ES6? if yes "import json from './json/data.json'" will work

Comment: using v-for directive

Comment: no i am not using es6 but i have imported by json and now i have to show the json data

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Assign the import to  a data property

```
<script>
      import json from './json/data.json'
      export default{
          data(){
              return{
                  myJson: json
              }
          }
      }
</script>
```

then loop through the `myJson` property in your template using `v-for`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="data in myJson">{{data}}</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**NOTE**

If the object you want to import is static i.e does not change then assigning it to a data property would make no sense as it does not need to be reactive.

Vue converts all the properties in the `data` option to getters/setters for the properties to be reactive. So it would be unnecessary and overhead for vue to setup getters/setters for data which is not going to change. See [Reactivity in depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html).

So you can create a custom option as follows:

```
<script>
          import MY_JSON from './json/data.json'
          export default{
              //custom option named myJson
                 myJson: MY_JSON
          }
    </script>
```

then loop through the custom option in your template using [`$options`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options):

```
<template>
        <div>
            <div v-for="data in $options.myJson">{{data}}</div>
        </div>
    </template>
```

Comment: @HaroonAslam then how do you want it?

Comment: @HaroonAslam show your json data so helping you would be easier

Comment: http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=4b5f37eec8bce13bcb21bd86ad7fe8d5 

@Vamsi

Comment: Great detail on the `$options` approach, I'd been using `created()` for non-reactive data - this is better

Comment: What is root dir?

Comment: Also this just doesn't work. It should not be market correct.

Comment: @mathtick I'm kinda late to the party, but it seems, that the root directory is the directory the current view is in. So I was trying to do that in my `src/views/Component.vue`. My JSON file is `src/mock-data/data.json`. Using `import data from '../mock-data/data.json'` (relative path) worked for me. I am a newbie in regards to Vue, so I assume I'll be moving these things into some service or something, but it is okay for now.

Answer (score 18):

If your file looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "firstname": "toto",
        "lastname": "titi"
    },
    {
        "firstname": "toto2",
        "lastname": "titi2"
    },
]
```

You can do:

```
import json from './json/data.json';
// ....
json.forEach(x => { console.log(x.firstname, x.lastname); });
```

Comment: it is in multiple array form

Comment: it shows the data but in string form not accessible using index value but i can acces them in console using index

Comment: @HaroonAslam You should update your question with how you've been trying to use the json object.

Answer (score 16):

Typescript projects (I have typescript in SFC vue components), need to set `resolveJsonModule` compiler option to `true`.

In tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Happy coding :)

(Source https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have recently started working on a project using Vue JS, JSON Schema. I am trying to access nested JSON Objects from a JSON Schema file in the Vue app. I tried the below code and now I can load different JSON objects inside different Vue template tags.
In the script tag add the below code

```
import  {JsonObject1name, JsonObject2name} from 'your Json file path';
```

Now you can access JsonObject1,2 names in data section of export default part as below:

```
data: () => ({ 
  
  schema: JsonObject1name,
  schema1: JsonObject2name,   
  
  model: {} 
}),
```

Now you can load the schema, schema1 data inside Vue template according to your requirement. See below code for example :

```
      <SchemaForm id="unique name representing your Json object1" class="form"  v-model="model" :schema="schema" :components="components">
      </SchemaForm>  

      <SchemaForm id="unique name representing your Json object2" class="form" v-model="model" :schema="schema1" :components="components">
      </SchemaForm>
```

SchemaForm is the local variable name for @formSchema/native library. I have implemented the data of different JSON objects through forms in different CSS tabs.

I hope this answer helps someone. I can help if there are any questions.