# How to read json file in vue.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I am beginner in web development.
I am using vue-cli3.0 and local server.

```
<template>
    <div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
  components: {
  },
})

export default class Test extends Vue 
{
  mounted(){
      this.readJson("./resources/doc.json")
  }

    readJson(filePath) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET",filePath, false);
        console.log(request)
        // request.send(null)
        // var my_JSON_object = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        // alert (my_JSON_object.result[0]);
    }
}
</script>
```

When I console.log(request) , inside of request is like this.

> XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 1, timeout: 0,
>   withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …} onabort: null
>   onerror: null onload: null onloadend: null onloadstart: null
>   onprogress: null onreadystatechange: null ontimeout: null readyState:
>   1 response: "" responseText: "" responseType: "" responseURL: ""
>   responseXML: null status: 0 statusText: "" timeout: 0 upload:
>   XMLHttpRequestUpload {onloadstart: null, onprogress: null, onabort:
>   null, onerror: null, onload: null, …} withCredentials: false
>   **proto**: XMLHttpRequest

They are all null.

Please help me.

I can't write import here.

So I don't want to use import.

---

Thank you for a answer.

```
<template>
    <div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
  components: {
  },
})

export default class Test extends Vue 
{
  mounted(){
      this.readJson(require("./resources/doc.json"))
  }

    readJson(filePath) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET",filePath, false);
        console.log(request)
        request.send(null)
        var my_JSON_object = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        alert (my_JSON_object.result[0]);
    }
}
</script>
```

I changed my code like this.

But inside request is still same.

error

> vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:587 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook:
>   "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

---

But I found that inside "filePath.ngldoc" there were data!
Is this data javascript object?

Comment: I assume `./resources/doc.json` exists relative to your the `.vue` file you shared here?

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45566350/8284987

Comment: Also it might be helpful to log the contents of `request.responseText`.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `this.readJson(require("./resources/doc.json"))`.

See [the `vue-cli` dos on static asset handling](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling) for a detailed explanation of your available options.